# Javascript with the "async" attribute - can it change DOM elements that are defined below it?

Tags: javascript, html

The body of my HTML:

```
<body>
   <script async src="changeParContent.js"></script>
   <script> \\some irrelevant inline code that takes a long time to run
   </script>
   <p id='par1'>Initial text</p>
</body>
```

And here is changeParContent.js:

```
document.getElementById('par1').innerHTML = "The content was changed!"
```

I expected the Javascript to fail, since I use the async attribute. It means that the script will be downloaded and executed while the HTML is being parsed. Now, since I intentionally slow down the HTML parsing, I expected the javascript to run before the paragraph "p1" was defined.

I thought that I did the one thing you're not supposed to do - defining the DOM elements that are used in the async script below the script.

But it somehow works and the paragraph changes. How can it be?

Comment: well it works because async scripts will be loaded after the dom has finished to be parsed, even with normal scripts without async it will work, because your p element is not added dynamically, it's in the html returned from the server already. For a script to be executed, parsing of html has to be done, the script is part of the dom too, there is no way for a script to be executed before the dom parsing

Comment: @lk77 that's incorrect, async scripts don't wait for the DOM to load. You may be thinking of `defer`.

Comment: @JakeBrowning i replaced loaded by parsed to be more clear, i don't mean that async wait for dom content to be loaded

Comment: I still think it's not correct -- you'll notice that OP's example works in chrome, but not firefox. Async scripts don't run in any predictable fashion, and it's really down to the browser's implementation

Comment: I think it depends if it's a file or not

Comment: but yeah you right its not correct, i always though blocking scripts where executed first and then non-blocking scripts

Answer (score 2):

Async scripts don't really run in any predictable fashion, and it's mainly down to the browser's implementation. For example, you should find the the following works in Chrome:

```html
<body>
   <script async src="./changeParContent.js"></script>
   <script>
         function sleepFor(sleepDuration){
                var now = new Date().getTime();
                while(new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration){ /* Do nothing */ }
        }
        sleepFor(5000);
   </script>
   <p id='par1'>Initial text</p>
</body>
```

However in Firefox the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

It seems that in both browsers, the slow inline `script` blocks both the `async` script from running and the rest of the DOM from loading. Then after this slow script runs, the `async` script runs in parallel with the rest of the DOM loading. In my experiments, it seems that in Chrome the race is won by the DOM, which causes no errors as the element is loaded by the time the `async` script runs. However in my Firefox test, the race is won by the `async` script which throws an error.

I think the lesson here is to trust best practices, even if it looks like there's no issues with your code.

Comment: For me it works for both Chrome and Firefox... I'm making a small presentation on the subject so I want to show how async may not work when changing the DOM... but it keeps working...

Comment: did you factor network latency ?

Comment: @MatanL. Try making the slow script also external (i.e. `<script src="./slowScript.js">`), or add some artificial latency to the `async` script as @Lk77 mentioned

Comment: @JakeBrowning making it external seemed to help - the problem sometimes manifests itself

Comment: Well, fact that the solution is so unpredictable is kind of a testament to your point that using async in this way is a bad idea